# $\int_0^1 \sqrt {\tan^{-1}x}\space dx=$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate $$\int_0^1 \sqrt {\tan^{-1}x}\space dx\qquad ?$$ Is there an elementary expression or value for it? (though I know that there is no elementary expression for $\int \sqrt {\tan^{-1}x}\space dx$)  .

Comment: Let $0<\chi<1$ be such that $\tan(\chi^2)=1$. Then your integral is $$\chi-\int_0^\chi \tan x^2\,{\rm d}x$$ You can approximate the integral with Taylor polynomials to any degree of accuracy, and do the same for $\chi$ (first).

Answer (score 5):

You can have a solution as an infinite sum

> $$\int_0^1 \sqrt {\tan^{-1}x}\space dx = \frac{\sqrt {\pi }}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {\pi }}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {\psi^{(2\,n+1
> )} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) }{ 16^n\left( 4\,n+3 \right)  \left( 2\,
> n+1 \right) !}} \sim 0.6298233443,$$

where $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: A little explanation please.

Comment: @Arjang: I'll try to do this latter. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal: I also got , $ \frac {\sqrt \pi}{2} - \frac {2}{\sqrt \pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n  (1-4^n)B_{2n}\pi^{2n}}{(2n)! (4n-1) 4^n}$ , where $B_{m} $ is the $m$ th "Bernoulli number".

Answer (score -1):

By using the formula http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/7/2/a/72a1058ad2087aec467af24bddcf9479.png, we have $\int_0^1\sqrt{\tan^{-1}x}~dx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2^n}\sqrt{\tan^{-1}\dfrac{m}{2^n}}$

Comment: +1 for the nice formula, what is the page that talks about it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals#Definite_integrals_lacking_closed-form_antiderivatives

Comment: This is a suggestion of a numerical method, I suppose?

Comment: @Tunococ, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals#Definite_integrals_lacking_closed-form_antiderivatives claims that http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/7/2/a/72a1058ad2087aec467af24bddcf9479.png is an exact formula.

Comment: @doraemonpaul I did not say that the formula is not exact.